# How do I use jQuery to redirect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a HTML form to submit to a jQuery validation which then sends information to a PHP processing page through ajax.

Everything works 100% apart from when everything comes back true I can't get the page to redirect to a success page.

The code I have is:

```
$.post(url,{ username: value_login.val(), firstname: value_firstname.val(), lastname: value_lastname.val(), email: value_email.val(), password: value_password.val()} , function(data) {

    if(data == 'success'){

        window.location.href = "http://example.com/Registration/Success/";
    } else {
       $('#error').text('error');
    }

});
```

I'm thinking you can't redirect using the `window.location.href` function.

Comment: Did you `alert(data)` to actually see what value is returned?

Comment: `console.log(data)`. Stop using `alert()` for debugging lol.

Comment: please also tell what is the error that you are getting on running the above code...Also we need to know the format of the data that is getting returned by the server...please tell that

Comment: @arshA the error on the console states: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://xxx.com/Registration/Success/ but this cant be because there is a url for this

Comment: when you get an error like that that means either the URL is wrong or server is down.... open a new tab and paste the url in the address bar to see if you can access the server

Comment: @Robert - When I follow [that URL](http://xxx.com/Registration/Success/), I also get a 404.

Comment: so that means that the url does not exist.. that post request will never get called

Comment: @arshA that is because i dont own the xxx.com lol it is on my local machine so i do not have an external url to give. So instead of giving http://Localhost/ i gave xxx.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You forgot the HTTP part:

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com/Registration/Success/";
```

Comment: Sliber this was just a typo on the demo code on here. I have the http on live code

Comment: @Robert - Does your server return a string? Can you show us your server-side code?

Comment: everything works fine apart from it gives an error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) xxx.com/Registration/Success but this is not true, is it trying to find a file and trying to retrieve data?

Comment: @Robert - Then the `url` you're passing to `$.post` is wrong.

Comment: your web service should return a data if you are specifying a data == success. it will definitely look for some response from server.

Answer (score 8):

Via Jquery:

```
$(location).attr('href','http://example.com/Registration/Success/');
```

Comment: work like a charm!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why this happening.

After looking at my settings on my wamp, i did not check http headers, since activated this, it now works.

Thank you everyone for trying to solve this. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({  type: "POST",
           url: url,  
          data: { username: value_login.val(), firstname: value_firstname.val(), 
                  lastname: value_lastname.val(), email: value_email.val(),
                  password: value_password.val()
                },
          dataType: "json"
       success: success// -> call your func here  
      });
```

Hope This helps

Comment: I dont have a problem with the ajax, that works fine, the problem i am getting is the redirect after.

Comment: putting your code in success will redirect it, just try