# Redirect URL after AJAX in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call and am trying to redirect my page after it makes the call to another URL. However, it just refreshes the page. What can I do to redirect my page?

```
<button onclick="SignUp()" class="btn btn-success text-center">Submit Information</button>

function SignUp() {

    var first_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    var last_name = document.getElementById('last_name').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'signup.php',
        data: { "first_name": first_name, "last_name": last_name },
        async: false,
        success: (function () {
            window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use jQuery to redirect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591428/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-redirect)

Comment: i've tried that post already, does not work, still just acts like a refresh. after the ajax call, the url became www.example.com/signup/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
  window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

### EDIT

As button is in form its default behavior is submit

So you have to add `type="button"` to button like

```
<button type="button" >Submit Information</button>
```

### OR

You need to use  `return false`

*HTML*

```
<button onclick="return SignUp()" >Submit Information</button>
```

*JavaScript*

```
function SignUp() {
    //Your code  
        return false;        
};
```

Comment: @user3147424, Do you really need form. Just try to use without form. And Please remove your comment so that we can continue interacting

Answer (score 1):

Your submit button is submitting the form before the success handler is processed.

Add `type="button"` so it isn't a submit button.

Comment: type="button" ended up being the final piece to the puzzle, thanks!

Comment: actually, it still does not redirect when there is data in the form. . .

Answer (score 0):

Since your button is in a form you need to add this to onClick or the page refreshes due to a form submit.

```
<button onclick="SignUp()"; return false" ...
```